# Python running multiple programs as administrator consecutively

Tags: python, subprocess, installation

I have two programs both of which are installers that have to be executed as Administrator. I am trying to write a python script that will run both of those programs. I figured I could just call subprocess on both of these programs, but this does not work.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:Administrator','Program1'])

subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:Administrator','Program2'])
```

This is the code I have come up with from a little searching on the internet, but this is not actually running either of the programs. What happens when I run this is A terminal pops up and you have to type in the Administrator password, but then after that nothing happens. I think the problem might have to do with calling these right after another. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
import subprocess as Popen
import subprocess as sp

prog = sp.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', 'NeedsAdminPrivilege.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
prog.stdin.write('password') #in case if u need to write password
prog.communicate()
```

for further reference https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx

Comment: Did this work when you tried it. It is not actually running the programs when I try this code.